# backend order create: default billing = shipping address + add to addressbook

Tags: orders, backend

we enter a lot of orders via backend. And for every single order I have to click: 
 - shipping address = same as billing
 - save to address book

How can we set this to default (avoiding these two extra clicks)

Merci!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own theme for admin. Let's call it `custom`.

Add this in any of the config files of your local modules (or create a new one) as a child for the `<config>` tag:

```
<stores>
    <admin>
        <design>
            <package>
                <name>default</name>
            </package>
            <theme>
                <default>custom</default>
            </theme>
        </design>
    </admin>
</stores>
```

This will make the admin use your theme.

Now copy the following file to your new theme keeping the path

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/form/address.phtml`
In this you will find the checkbox for 'Same as billing'

```
<input type="checkbox" id="order-shipping_same_as_billing" name="shipping_same_as_billing" onchange="order.setShippingAsBilling(this.checked)" <?php if($this->getIsAsBilling()): ?>checked<?php endif; ?>/>
```

Make it checked by default.

And the checkbox for save in address book.

```
<input name="<?php echo $this->getForm()->getHtmlNamePrefix()?>[save_in_address_book]" type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->getForm()->getHtmlIdPrefix()?>save_in_address_book" value="1" <?php if (!$this->getDontSaveInAddressBook() && $this->getAddress()->getSaveInAddressBook()):?> checked="checked"<?php endif;?>/>
```

Also make it checked by default.

Comment: And is there no way to do it via: $this->getIsAsBilling() defaulting to true (via backend or some other trick?

Comment: In my case, it IS checked by default, how do I clear it? We need to confirm it is or is not...