# Admin order create: Shipping same as Billing always checked: can I clear that?

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml, forms

My situation is the opposite of [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/2674/)... and my version is 1.7.0.1

When creating a new order in the back end for phone orders, we're finding that the "Same As Billing Address" tickbox is always checked. My shipping staff are sometimes shipping orders incorrectly due to this because somehow, the shipping address actually isn't the billing address.

Of course, I tried editing app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/form/address.phtml on line 67 to remove `<?php if($this->getIsAsBilling()): ?>checked<?php endif; ?>` from the checkbox, but that is absolutely not the solution. :P Yes, the form then comes up NOT checked, but if you then check it, it stays cleared when it should now be changed.

Which makes me think I am looking at the symptom and the problem is elsewhere.

Help, please, in finding a way to uncheck that box at the beginning of the order?

Comment: You guys are all missing the point. We should not have to hack core files or create custom extensions for something as simple as this. The Magento team should fix this bug. I'm using Magento 2.1.7 and this bug is STILL present! It's extremely frustrating to have bugs as large as this go untouched for all this time. Magento is FULL of bugs and very slow to fix them. I'm never using it for another project again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guys this is just horrible solutions. You can’t modify core files (even less copying them to /local) and your problem is related to a backend issue and you end up modifying a file that will also alter the frontend.

If you check this controller : `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController`

You will see there is a function called `_processActionData` and it sets the `setShippingAsBilling` to 1.

Just create an extension and add an observer on `adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data` to apply the modification you want.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look @  app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php

At Line # 246 in `_beforeSave()`

```
if ($this->getAddressType() == Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_SHIPPING
    && $this->getSameAsBilling() === null
) {
    $this->setSameAsBilling(1);
}
```

to

```
if ($this->getAddressType() == Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_SHIPPING
        && $this->getSameAsBilling() === null
            && $this->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getData('customer_address_id') == $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData('customer_address_id')
) {
        $this->setSameAsBilling(1);
}
```

To avoid making change to core you can create a custom module that overwrite `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address` see http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/53671/ or copy to `local` folder with the same directory structure

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php` file. Find function `_beforeSave()` and review these lines:

```
 if ($this->getAddressType() == Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_SHIPPING
            && $this->getSameAsBilling() === null
        ) {
            $this->setSameAsBilling(1);
        }
```

These lines tell us by default shipping address will be same as billing address for new quote (also **same_as_billing** column of **sales_flat_quote_address** table is NULL by default). You should change as:

```
$this->setSameAsBilling(0);
```

Comment: You should never modify a core file.

Comment: @philwinkle Now that have experience with *overrides*, I edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php` and find the protected method `_initShippingAddressFromOrder(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order)`:

```
$this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCustomerAddressId('');
```

**To**

```
$orderShippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
$quoteShippingAddress = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()
    ->setCustomerAddressId('')
    ->setSameAsBilling($orderShippingAddress && $orderShippingAddress->getSameAsBilling());
```

You should never modify a core file. Just create a new module and rewrite the class.